# can i boot from a blue ray?

Tags: boot, blu-ray

the easy telled question is in the title.. the hard one is.. can i boot windows 11 (LEAKED) from a blue ray the size of windows 11 (THE LEAKED VERSION!) is 4,5GB big i downloaded LITERALLY 3 hours or more! and it doesnt fit on my DVD`s CdBurnerXP just tells me needed size : 4,54gb (or something) and actual size 4,38gb so on the dvd it tells its 4,7gb big but it dont want to burn it so i thinked about buing BlueRays and burn those with a blue ray burner please answer if you have an solution for me and for everyone tells me : "create a boot usb stick" or something idk how to do this tutorials for doing something like making usb boot sticks are also welcome! so i hope someone have some knowledge here

here is the link for windows11 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Op9HOvIj16c

Comment: Use USB. Nobody uses optical media for installers since MANY years ago.

Comment: [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/), Have you tried it?

Comment: There’s Dual Layer DVDs. But yes, use a USB flash drive.

Comment: Just so you know, the PC must support Secure Boot and TPM 2.0 when installing W11 or installation will halt.